# WebDriver explicit wait in Scala

Tags: scala, selenium, webdriver

How would the [Java explicit wait example here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html) be written in Scala:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
      return d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
    }});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would look very similar. Some types and parenthesis could be omitted. But as long there is no special Scala API that uses some of the Scala features, it would look something like this (maybe more dots could be comitted, too):

```
val driver: WebDriver = new FireFoxDriver
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
val myDynamicElement = new WebdriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  new ExpectedCondition[WebElement] {
    override def apply(d: WebDriver) = d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"))
  })
```

Comment: there should be a var/val before myDynamicElement

Comment: the compiler complained until this line was changed: `override def apply(d: WebDriver) = {`

Comment: You can also remove braces after that `=`, since there is just one expression.

Comment: It's actually `WebDriverWait` (uppercase `D`). Note for others: this API is part of the [Selenium Support](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support) library.

Answer (score 0):

I have helper class for shorter and cleaner code in Scala:

```
case class SeleniumHelper(timeOut: Int) {
  def waitFor(driver: WebDriver, f: (WebDriver) => WebElement) : WebElement = {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut).until(
     new ExpectedCondition[WebElement] {
      override def apply(d: WebDriver) = f(d)
    })
  }

  def test() = {
  val driver: WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver
  driver.get("http://www.abksystem.com")
  waitFor(driver, _.findElement(By.className("module module-Menu")))
  }
}
```